# Hashcode and excluding fields

Tags: java, hash, hashcode

According to Bloch's advice on hashCode:

> You may ignore any field whose value can be computed from fields
>   included in the computation

I don't understand this. Can someone give a real example of this one? I assume that any class that can generate a field from other fields would only store it in another variable for performance reasons. But what does this have to do with the hashcode contract?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class Example {
  final int a;
  final int b;
  final int c;

  Example(int a, int b) { this.a = a; this.b = b; this.c = a + b; }
}
```

There's no point in including `c` in the `hashCode` calculation here: any instance for which `a` and `b` are equal will also have `c`s equal.

```
Objects.hash(this.a, this.b, this.c) == Objects.hash(that.a, that.b, that.c)
  <=>
Objects.hash(this.a, this.b) == Objects.hash(that.a, that.b)
```

So all you're doing is "perturbing" the hash code by including `c`, i.e. making it a different value, but not in a meaningful way.

---

A practical example of this is in `String`: `String` has a field, `hash`, which stores the value of the hash code, to avoid repeated calculation ([source](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/lang/String.java#1453)):

```
public int hashCode() {
    int h = hash;  // <-- hash is a member variable.
    if (h == 0 && value.length > 0) {
        char val[] = value;

        for (int i = 0; i < value.length; i++) {
            h = 31 * h + val[i];
        }
        hash = h;
    }
    return h;
}
```

Perhaps obviously, this can't be included in the hash code calculation! But it can be derived from other fields in the class.

Comment: I suspected that but how can this be a real code? Why would you actually keep a field `c` in practice?

Comment: @Jim either for performance, or for notational convenience (i.e. to avoid having to write `a+b` or `getC()` everywhere).

Answer (score 1):

Consider a class where you have more fields

```
class MyClass {
   String name;
   String surname;
   String fullName;
}
```

In this class, for the generations of hashcode, the only fields that make sense add are`name` and`surname`. The remaining field `fullName` which is generated by the others can be ignored.

Answer (score 1):

> But what does this have to do with the hashcode contract?

It doesn't make part of the `hashcode()` contract. You should rather consider it as a good practice to implement it in an effective way (as it spares some helpless computations).

In fact a good implementation of `hashCode()` should rely on the same fields as those used by the `equals()` method.

If you have a class with 3 fields, for example `Addition` :

```
class Addition {
  private float operandOne;
  private float operandTwo;
  private float result;
}
```

You don't need to use `result` in the `equals()` method because `result` is in a some way a redundant information and you don't need it to identify in a unique way a `Addition` instance.
You know that if `operandOne` and `operandTwo` from one `Addition` instance matches with the  `operandOne` and `operandTwo` from another `Addition` instance, it is enough to consider them equals.

In the `hashcode()` method, it is the same thing.

Comment: In practice why would `result` be a member field of `Addition`?

Comment: In practice, not common I agree with you but It is just an example to show a simple derived value. You could replace  `Addition` by `BigComputations` that contains a final result but also derived results from this result.